# how to append inventory system from item list?

Tags: javascript

How to add item from items list to inventory and print it?

```
var items = {
    knife: {
        name: "Knife"
    }
};

var inventory = {};

//document.write(inventory....);
```

Or am I not understanding something and making everything wrong? maybe objects is wrong choice?

I want output just to print item name like knife. But not from var items - Print it from inventory

Everything should work like picking up item from ground.

Comment: your question is not clear, what do you want the output be

Comment: Your question is not a question

Comment: I want output just to print item name like knife. But not from var items - Print it from inventory

Comment: `inventory.knife = items.knife;` then `document.write(inventory.knife.name);` ?

Comment: Do you mean `var inventory = {}; inventory.knife = items.knife; alert(inventory.knife.name);`?

Comment: i want to implement something like picking up item and it appears in inventory

Comment: @user2351722 Seriously what you're saying makes no sense. You need to explain what you want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using the wrong data structure for your inventory, unless you want to be able to pickup a single item per kind, you should be using an `array`.

```
var inventory = []; //empty inventory

inventory.push(items.knife); //pickup a knife
inventory.push(items.knife); //pickup another knife
```

Loop over the inventory and alert the item names:

```
for (var i = 0, len = inventory.length; i < len; i++) {
    alert(inventory[i].name);
}
```

*Please note that the objects in the `inventory` are references to the `items.knife` object. If you want to clone those objects instead, have a look at [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object).*

Comment: yes thanks but getting error unnexpected token ) HERE : (var i = 0, len = inventory.length; i++) {

Comment: @user2351722, Sorry, I forgot a part to my loop construct ;)